# Returning pointer from a function in c

Tags: c

What's the problem with the following code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *a=pointer_return();

}

int* pointer_return()
{
     int a=10;
    return &a;
}
```

It gives me error

```
demo.c: In function ‘main’:
demo.c:5:9: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
demo.c: At top level:
demo.c:9:6: error: conflicting types for ‘pointer_return’
demo.c:5:9: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘pointer_return’ was here
```

Comment: What do you think it is?

Comment: `pointer_return` should be defined either before its use or add a prototype. Other than that returning address of a local variable is wrong.

Comment: You're returning the pointer to a local variable of `pointer_return`. The variable is out of scope after turn (it's space on the stack is relinquished).

Comment: Down-vote should mark duplicate instead voting down-every one.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? It gives a minimal compiling example and the corresponding error message. Seems perfectly fine to me. @DmitryBrant: How is your snarky comment helpful? Stackoverflow used to be a much more pleasant place ...

Answer (score 8):

The actual ERROR is occurring because you declared `pointer_return` AFTER you attempted to use it. So the C compiler doesn't know what it is when you referenced it. If you change the order, then the reference to `pointer_return` in the `int *a...` declaration is understood by the compiler:

```
int* pointer_return()
{
     int a=10;
    return &a;
}

int main()
{
    int *a=pointer_return();
}
```

Or resolved by:

```
int* pointer_return();

int main()
{
    int *a=pointer_return();
}

int* pointer_return()
{
    int a=10;
    return &a;
}
```

The error will go away, but you'll still get the warning about returning the address of a local variable, as everyone has pointed out. Returning the address of a local variable will result in undefined behavior if the return value is later dereferenced.

Answer (score 0):

The variable you are returning a pointer to is on the stack, which mean's it becomes invalid / illegal to reference it once the function returns.

Comment: Uhhm, that's a reason to downvote the question, not the answers.

Comment: Probably because it doesn't address the error in the question.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes Yes but some users do like this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are returning the address of a local variable. As soon as the function goes out of scope, the variable goes out of scope and its address becomes meaningless. Therefore your pointer will hold an invalid address.

Comment: I guess because none of them did address the error in the question.

Comment: the error messages were not in the initial posts. they were added after the first answers

Comment: The original post was made at 13:51. A comment with the correct answer was made at 13:53. Neither has been edited. The first answer was posted 17 seconds after the comment. All the other answers were posted later.

Answer (score 0):

`int a=10` would go out of scope as soon as the call to `pointer_return` returns..

So,`*a` would point to invalid memory

---

You should do it this way

```
int* pointer_return()
{
     int *a=malloc(sizeof(int));
     *a=10;
     return a;
}
```